# changing React.js form values from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm not developing in React.js, but I'm working on a chrome extension that needs to programatically fill form values for different kinds of sites.

The site uses React.js, and I'm filling the value in the usual way with:

```
element = document.querySelector("input[name=firstName]");
element.value = "something";
```

When the user clicks the submit button, he gets this error for that form element, even if the element has a value:
"This information is required."

It doesn't help if fire "change" event for that element.

```
evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

There is some method in the React.js framework I need to call to programatically change the value? Help from React.js experienced users is appreciated!

Comment: A found a solution. Call element.select(); before changing the value.

Comment: Then answer your own question with that and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Call `element.select();` before changing the value.

Comment: I have the very same use case, and this is not working for me on a number input. Values get reset to whatever it we previously.

Comment: Does not work when testing from the Chrome console.